# How to install gcc -4.8.4 using homebrew in os x 10.10

Tags: c++, gcc, homebrew

I have cloned someone's c++ code from github but failed to make it. The author told me that the version of gcc he used is 4.8.4 and he could successfully run it. So I installed gcc48 using `brew install homebrew/versions/gcc48` and specify the version of `gcc` in the `makefile` placed in his code folder.

However, an error is got during the compile:

```
g++-4.8  -c -pipe -O3 BurstyBTM.cpp -o BurstyBTM.o 
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'Pvec<double> BurstyBTM::compute_pz_b(Biterm&)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:129:23: error: could not convert 'pz.Pvec<T>::normalize<double>(0.0)' from 'void' to 'Pvec<double>'
   return pz.normalize();
                       ^
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'void BurstyBTM::save_pz(std::string)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:158:41: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'Pvec<double>' requested
   Pvec<double> pz = nb_z.normalize(alpha);
                                         ^
BurstyBTM.cpp: In member function 'void BurstyBTM::save_pw_z(std::string)':
BurstyBTM.cpp:164:37: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'Pmat<double>' requested
   Pmat<double> pw_z = nwz.normr(beta);
                                     ^
make: *** [BurstyBTM.o] Error 1
```

How can I install the gcc with version 4.8.4 specifically? Otherwise, how can I deal with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `BurstyBTM.` come from?

Comment: There are `BurstyBTM.o` `BurstyBTM.h` and `BurstyBTM.cpp` in the folder

Comment: Can you post the error lines that are above `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`?

Comment: @purplepsycho I have edited the question already.

Answer (score 0):

You try to compile your code with an C compiler instead of a C++ one.

In make file, replace

```
CC=gcc-4.8
```

by

```
CC=g++-4.8
```

If you don't have g++ installed, install it with

```
brew install gcc48 --enable-cxx
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But got this error this time: `g++-4.8 BurstyBTM.o main.o -o bbtm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BurstyBTM::run(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bbtm] Error 1
`

Comment: did you try `make clean` before?

Comment: Yes, but I think it maybe unnecessary:`make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.`

Comment: Your problem may come from the fact that `.o` files has been compiled with `gcc` instead of `g++`, so you should detele `.o` files before running make again.

Comment: You are right! But another error occurs, please see the updates.

Comment: I think you should open a new question: You've got several problems: <br> * first, you had to create the good makefile, <br> * then the code you try to compile has some defects. <br> I think the two issues are differents.